# How to solve "error TS2688: Cannot find type definition"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsc

I am having this error in our project. We do not use any package that is called `docs`

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'docs'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'docs'
```

`tsconfig.json` looks like this

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2017.object", "es2015.promise", "es7", "es2018.promise", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "outDir": "./build-tsc/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/*"],
            "@platform/*": ["src/*"],
            "@resource/*": ["resource/*"],
            "@tool/*": ["tool/*"],
            "pixi-viewport": ["node_modules/pixi-viewport"],
            "pixi-viewport/*": ["node_modules/pixi-viewport/*"],
            "populate": ["src/Utility/Populate/"]
        },
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types", "node_modules/reflect-metadata"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules", 
        "editor",
        "test",
        "tool",
        "dist", 
        "build", 
        "build-tsc", 
        "resource",
    ]
}
```

`package.json` looks like this

Any tips on how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you find any occurrence of `docs` in your project?

Comment: nothing relevant. Just some "docs" in some comments and some native code that mentions docs paths. But nothing related to ts/js

Comment: Where does the error point to?

Comment: Why are you doing this -> `"pixi-viewport": ["node_modules/pixi-viewport"],`   And -> `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types",`  You shouldn't be altering module resolution for `npm` packages.

Comment: Removing the `typeRoots` overrides did the trick. Thanks